# Case 3 doesn't enter into the loop and Case 5 doesn't order properly the names of the employees

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing an app that has to do the following :

We will develop a Bank application that saves us the branches (numerical), and the employees of each branch. This application should ask for the screen to give us how many branches the bank has, and then, for each branch, how many employees work there (Multidimensional Arrays in Java).

The user will give us by screen, for each branch number, one by one the employees that form it, passing us the first name, first name and second last name.

Once all the data is saved, a menu will be displayed on the screen to choose between the following options:

Screen all employees of one of the branches (the one chosen by the user).
Screen which branch an employee belongs to (the one chosen by the user).
Display how many employees there are with the same first name (the one chosen by the user).
Screen how many employees are in total in the Bank.
Display all employees in the center in alphabetical order.

```
public class Banco2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner construction
        Scanner Entrada=new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner used to read Strings
        Scanner ent=new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner used to read Integer variables 
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------//
        //Variables used for the problem
        int sucursales;
        int options;
        int numsucursal;//Variable used for the case 1
        int numbempleados;//Variable used for the case 1
        int numeroempleado;
        String surname;
        String empleados;//Variable used for the case 2
        String Apellido;//Varible used for the case 3
        int empl;
        int numeroempleadototal=0;//Variable used as a counter in the case 4
        int aux=0;//Variable used in case 5 to go counting
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        //We ask the user for the number of branches
        System.out.println("Introduce el numero de sucursales");
        sucursales=ent.nextInt();//We read the number of branches that the user introduces
        //Construction of our multidimensional array
        String banco [][]=new String[sucursales][];
        // i rows, j columns
        //In this loop we fill in the position
        for (int i=0;i<banco.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduceme la cantidad de empleados que trabajan en la sucursal " + ( i+1 ));
            numeroempleado=ent.nextInt();
            //We assign it to the object bank 
            banco[i]=new String[numeroempleado];
        }
        //We are going to fill in the array
        for (int i=0;i<banco.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<banco[i].length;j++) {
                System.out.println("Introduceme el nombre de los empleados " + ( i+1));//We use i+1 to know the branches that the user is filliing in 
                banco[i][j]=Entrada.nextLine(); 
            }
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        do {
        //Menu options
        System.out.println("Ingrese una de las opciones que desea hacer");
        System.out.println("1.Sacar por pantalla todos los empleados de unas sucursales");
        System.out.println("2.Sacar por pantalla a qué sucursal pertenece un empleado");
        System.out.println("3.Sacar por pantalla cuántos empleados hay con el mismo primer apellido");
        System.out.println("4.Sacar por pantalla cuántos empleados hay en total en el Banco.");
        System.out.println("5.Saca por pantalla todos los empleados del centro ordenados alfabéticamente.");
        //We read the option introduced
        options=ent.nextInt();
        switch(options) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Introduce la sucursal del empleado");
                numsucursal=ent.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Introduce el numero del empleado");
                numbempleados=ent.nextInt();
                System.out.println("El empleado es " + banco [numsucursal-1] [numbempleados]);
            break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Dime el nombre del empleado");
                empleados=Entrada.nextLine();
                //We go through the array to know the worker of the branch 
                for (int i=0;i<banco.length;i++) {
                    for (int j=0;j<banco[i].length;j++) {
                        if(empleados.equalsIgnoreCase(banco[i][j])) {
                        System.out.println("El empleado pertenece a la siguiente sucursal: " + (i + 1));
                    }//end of the second for
                }//end of the first for 
            }
            break;
            case 3: 
                //We ask the user for the surname
                System.out.println("Dime el apellido del empleado");
                //We read the surname introduced by the user
                Apellido=Entrada.nextLine();
                //We do two loops in order to go through the array
                for(int i=0;i<banco.length;i++) {
                    for (int j=0;j<banco.length;j++) {
                        surname=banco[i][j].substring(banco[i][j].indexOf(""),+1);
                        surname=Apellido.substring(0,Apellido.indexOf(""));
                        if(Apellido.equalsIgnoreCase(surname)) {
                            System.out.println("Los empleados con el apellido que quieres saber son: " +banco[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            break;
            case 4:
                    for (int i=0;i<banco.length;i++){
                        for (int j=0;j<banco[i].length;j++) {
                        numeroempleadototal ++;
                        System.out.println("Este es el numero total de empleados que hay en las sucursales " + numeroempleadototal);
                    }
                    }
            case 5:

                //We create the array with the names to order 
                String ordernames[] = new String[numeroempleadototal];
                aux=0;
                Arrays.sort(ordernames);
                for(int i=0;i<ordernames.length;i++) {
                    System.out.println("Nombres" + ordernames[i]);

                }
                break;
            default:
            System.out.println("Ha elegido usted la opcion incorrecta");
            break;
        }       
        }while(options!=6);
    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

Comment: In case 3 you are using for (int j=0;j<banco.length;j++),  try us ingfor (int j=0;j<banco[I].length;j++)  instead , and for case 4 use a break statement

Comment: Thank you for your help Adnan :)

Comment: Already solved:)